# Nested For-each Loop Sequence issue with values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, foreach, nested

``````````````````````````````````````````````
    var TeamLeadAuditsAndQuality = unitofwork.AuditNewRepository.SQLQuery<SPTotalAuditAndQualityOfOfMonthByTeamLead_Result>("SPTotalAuditAndQualityOfOfMonthByTeamLead").ToList();
    var TeamLeadFeedBacks = unitofwork.AuditNewRepository.SQLQuery<SPTotalFeedBackOfOfMonthByTeamLead_Result>("SPTotalFeedBackOfOfMonthByTeamLead").ToList();

            foreach (var items in TeamLeadAuditsAndQuality)
            {
                TeamLeadMonthlyResult Result = new TeamLeadMonthlyResult();
                Result.TeamLead = items.TeamLead;
                Result.MonthlyAudits = Convert.ToInt32(items.TotalAuditsOfCRU);
                Result.MonthlyQuality = items.Average;

                foreach (var item in TeamLeadFeedBacks)
                {
                    Result.MonthlyFeedbacks = Convert.ToInt32(item.TotalFeedbackOfCRU);
                }
                List.Add(Result);
            }
            model.TeamLeadMonthlyResultVMList = List;

            return View(model);
        }
                       `````````````````````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````````````````

The Above is my Code and i am getting data from stored procedure and for this i am using for each loop to iterate data but there is one issue that is i want to get the data in sequence that 1st row of 1st list and 1st row of second list and 2nd for 2nd n so on but i m getting the result in format that second list iterate fully and i got the same ans in whole column like this

[output image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiS1f.png)

the red column is repeating because 2nd foreach loop iterate fully and get the same ans i want to restrict it and get the ans in sequence please help me how will i do that

Comment: you can use for loop insed of foreach once you go with for you have index values

Comment: Thank you i did it in some other way But Thanks for your Support

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop.

```
var TeamLeadAuditsAndQuality =unitofwork.AuditNewRepository.SQLQuery<SPTotalAuditAndQualityOfOfMonthByTeamLead_Result>("SPTotalAuditAndQualityOfOfMonthByTeamLead").ToList();
            var TeamLeadFeedBacks = unitofwork.AuditNewRepository.SQLQuery<SPTotalFeedBackOfOfMonthByTeamLead_Result>("SPTotalFeedBackOfOfMonthByTeamLead").ToList();
                for(var i=0 ;i < TeamLeadAuditsAndQuality.Count; i++)
                    {
                        TeamLeadMonthlyResult Result = new TeamLeadMonthlyResult();
                        Result.TeamLead = TeamLeadAuditsAndQuality[i].TeamLead;
                        Result.MonthlyAudits = Convert.ToInt32(TeamLeadAuditsAndQuality[i].TotalAuditsOfCRU);
                        Result.MonthlyQuality = TeamLeadAuditsAndQuality[i].Average;

if(i<= TeamLeadFeedBacks.Count)                        
                            Result.MonthlyFeedbacks = Convert.ToInt32(TeamLeadFeedBacks[i].TotalFeedbackOfCRU);

                        List.Add(Result);
                    }
                    model.TeamLeadMonthlyResultVMList = List;

                    return View(model);
                }
```